# Restricting swap usage for a process managed via systemd

Tags: linux, swap, systemd

I am trying to restrict the swap usage of a process using `MemorySwapMax` as mentioned in the [doc](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/systemd.resource-control.5.html) with Ubuntu 18.04.

Environment

```
ubuntu@vrni-platform:/usr/lib/systemd/system$ uname -a
Linux vrni-platform 4.15.0-143-generic #147-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 14 16:10:11 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

ubuntu@vrni-platform:/usr/lib/systemd/system$ systemctl --version
systemd 237
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid
```

My systemd unit file looks like below

```
[Unit]
Description=My service
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0
[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=support
MemoryMax=2000M
KillMode=process
MemoryAccounting=true
OOMScoreAdjust=1000
MemorySwapMax=0
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -cp /home/support -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary -Xmx10000m MemoryConsumer 100 200 1
```

I tried to disable swap for this process by specifying 0 for `MemorySwapMax`. But it seems there was some [issue](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/13826) in systemd which is fixed in systemd 239.

So I also tried setting `MemorySwapMax=1M`. But that also seems to be not restricting the swap memory usage for this systemd service.

The documentation for `MemorySwapMax` states this

```
This setting is supported only if the unified control group hierarchy is used and disables MemoryLimit=.
```

So as mentioned in this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/471495/364181) I can see cgroup v2 enabled on my setup.

```
ubuntu@vrni-platform:/tmp/debraj$ sudo mount -t cgroup2 none /tmp/debraj
ubuntu@vrni-platform:/tmp/debraj$ ls -l /tmp/debraj/
total 0
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Jul  2 17:13 cgroup.controllers
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Jul  2 17:13 cgroup.max.depth
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Jul  2 17:13 cgroup.max.descendants
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Jun 30 14:42 cgroup.procs
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Jul  2 17:13 cgroup.stat
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Jul  2 17:13 cgroup.subtree_control
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Jul  2 17:13 cgroup.threads
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Jun 30 14:42 init.scope
drwxr-xr-x 87 root root 0 Jul  2 15:05 system.slice
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 0 Jun 30 15:22 user.slice
ubuntu@vrni-platform:/tmp/debraj$ sudo umount /tmp/debraj
```

MemoryConsumer.java is like below

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MemoryConsumer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        int size = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int count = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        int sleepMs = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        List<ByteBuffer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<byte[]> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
            list1.add(ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(size*1024*1024));
            //list2.add(new byte [size*1024*1024]);
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Allocated memory " + (i*size) + " MB\n" + (end-start) + " ms");
            Thread.sleep(sleepMs);
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone suggest what could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered in systemd mailing list.

[Link1](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2021-July/046662.html)

Re-posting relevant parts.

> Looks like your Ubuntu version is using the "hybrid" cgroup mode by
> default. Cgroup v2 is indeed *enabled* in your kernel, but not
> necessarily
> *in use* – in the hybrid mode, systemd still mounts all resource controllers (cpu, memory, etc.) in v1 mode and only sets up its own
> process tracking in the v2 tree. See `findmnt`.
>
> You could boot with the systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=1 kernel
> option to switch everything to cgroups v2, but if you're using
> container software (docker, podman) make sure those are cgroups
> v2-compatible.

[Link2](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2021-July/046680.html)

> Hello Debraj.
>
> On Thu, Jul 08, 2021 at 05:10:44PM +0530, Debraj Manna  wrote:
>
> > > > Linux vrni-platform 4.15.0-143-generic #147-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 14 16:10:11 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
> > > > [...]
> > > > GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="audit=1 rootdelay=180 nousb net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0
> > > > fsck.mode=force fsck.repair=yes ipv6.disable=1
> > > > systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=1"
> >
> > Even after making these changes MemorySwapMax not taking into effect.
>
> You need to add also swapaccount=1, swap accounting is enabled by
> default only since kernel v5.8.